# Как создать responsive анимацию svg border?

Tags: css, css3, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я хочу создать  анимацию `border` для элемента кнопки. Дизайн состоит в том, что концы наклонного прямоугольника разрываются, а затем закрываются при наведении.

Вот что я пытаюсь сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот некоторый код и пример codepen:

```
a svg rect {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5;
  transition: 1s;
  stroke-dasharray: 100%;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

a:hover svg rect {
  stroke-dasharray: 0%;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

[Пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/adam-macaulay/pen/NQWKNY?editors=1100)

У меня проблемы с пониманием математики, лежащей в основе `stroke-dasharray`, но кажется, что это возможно без слишком сложной математики.

Другая проблема заключается в том, что кнопка должна быть отзывчивой. Таким образом, кнопка может содержать различное количество текста.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57103501/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вот, я думаю, самое лучшее, что вы можете сделать, чтобы создать кнопку автоматически реагирующую на изменение длины текста,  соответствующую вашим требованиям.

У этого решения есть пара недостатков:

1. Зазор в контуре кнопки различается по размеру в зависимости от длины текста.
2. Нужен довольно свежий браузер (для поддержки `pathLength` на элементе `<rect>`)

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.btn + .btn {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.btn svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.btn, .btn svg {
  overflow: visible;
}

.btn svg rect {
  fill: gold;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 47 3;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: skewX(-10deg) scale(1, -1);
  transition: all 0.75s;
}

.btn:hover svg rect {
  stroke-dasharray: 50 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" pathLength="100"/>
  </svg>
  <div class="label">Button</div>
</div>

<div class="btn">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" pathLength="100"/>
  </svg>
  <div class="label">Much longer button</div>
</div>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57115236/7394871): @Paul LeBeau

Comment: красиво +1 (5 символов нужно)

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов мне показалось это решение интересным, именно по причине респонсивности кнопки при увеличении, уменьшении длины текста.

Comment: вообще выглядит колоритно сочетания цветов черный и желтый .А анимация в самый раз.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо использования `skewed` элемента SVG я использую `polygon`. Таким образом, я могу рассчитать общую длину (длину периметра) `polygon`.

Я сделал это с помощью `javascript: console.log(poly.getTotalLength())`. Это дало мне `543,7`.

Для `stroke-dasharray` полигона я использую: `250, 21,85, где 250 + 21,85 = 543,7 / 2`.

Я анимирую `stroke-dashoffset` до 543,7 / 2 = 271,85; и `stroke-dasharray` до 271,85 0 (ход идет от 250 до 271,85 и разрыв от 21,85 до 0)

Еще одно изменение, которое я сделал: я использую элемент svg `<a>` вместо того, который вы используете, и у полигона есть `pointer-events:all;` Я добавил это, чтобы сделать его чувствительным к мышке, хотя `fill:none`

*Анимация по наведению мышки*

```css
polygon {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dasharray:250, 21.85;
  fill: none;
  transition: 1s;
  pointer-events:all;
}

polygon:hover{
  stroke: #ff0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 271.85;
  stroke-dasharray: 271.85 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 250 50" width="250">
  <a xlink:href="#" class="py-2 px-5">
    <text x="125" y="30" text-anchor="middle">Button Button Button</text>
    <polygon id="poly" points="2,48 220,48 248,2 30,2 2,48" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57108083/7394871):@enxaneta